# Regex extracting characters between last and second last occurance of character

Tags: php, regex

i am trying to extract the word in between the last `/` and the second last `/` - i.e. food in the following PHP example.

1. `$string = https://ss1.xxx/img/categories_v2/FOOD/fastfood` (would like to replace `$string` to `food`)
2. `$string = https://ss1.xxx/img/categories_v2/SHOPS/barbershop` (would like to replace `$string` to `shops`)

I am new to regex and tried `/[^/]*$` - however that is returning everying after the last `/`.. any help would be appreciated.. thanks!

I am using PHP.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
preg_match('#/([^/]*)/[^/]*$#', $string, $match);
echo $match[1];
```

You could also use:

```
$words = explode('/', $string);
echo $words[count($words)-2];
```

Comment: I'd also throw [`parse_url($string, PHP_URL_PATH)`](http://uk1.php.net/parse_url) somewhere in option 2 for sanity :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
$result = preg_replace_callback('~(?<=/)[^/]+(?=/[^/]*$)~', function ($m) {
  return strtolower($m[0]); }, $string);
```

Pattern details:

```
~            # pattern delimiter
(?<=/)       # zero width assertion (lookbehind): preceded by /
[^/]+        # all characters except / one or more times
(?=/[^/]*$)  # zero width assertion (lookahead): followed by /,
             # all that is not a / zero or more times, and the end of the string
~            # pattern delimiter
```

Comment: He wants to extract, not replace.

Answer (score 0):

Regex:

```
(\w+)(/[^/]+)$
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
    $string = "https://ss1.xxx/img/categories_v2/FOOD/fastfood";
    echo preg_replace("@(\w+)(/[^/]+)$@", "food$2", $string);
    $string = "https://ss1.xxx/img/categories_v2/SHOPS/barbershop";
    echo preg_replace("@(\w+)(/[^/]+)$@", "shops$2", $string);
?>
```